# Checking odd parity in clojure

Tags: clojure, functional-programming

I have the following functions that check for odd parity in sequence

```
(defn countOf[a-seq elem]
   (loop [number 0 currentSeq a-seq]
      (cond (empty? currentSeq) number
          (= (first currentSeq) elem) (recur (inc number) (rest currentSeq))
            :else (recur number (rest currentSeq))
      )
   )
 )

(defn filteredSeq[a-seq elemToRemove]
  (remove (set (vector (first a-seq))) a-seq)
  )

(defn parity [a-seq]
  (loop [resultset [] currentSeq a-seq]
    (cond (empty? currentSeq) (set resultset)
           (odd? (countOf currentSeq (first currentSeq))) (recur (concat resultset (vector(first currentSeq))) (filteredSeq currentSeq (first currentSeq)))
           :else (recur resultset (filteredSeq currentSeq (first currentSeq)))
    )
  )
)
```

for example **(parity [1 1 1 2 2 3]) -> (1 3)** that is it picks odd number of elements from a sequence.

1. Is there a better way to achieve this?
2. How can this be done with **reduce** function of clojure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I decided to make more idiomatic versions of your code, so I could really see what it was doing:

```
;; idiomatic naming
;; no need to rewrite count and filter for this code
;; putting item and collection in idiomatic argument order
(defn count-of [elem a-seq]
  (count (filter #(= elem %) a-seq)))

;; idiomatic naming
;; putting item and collection in idiomatic argument order
;; actually used the elem-to-remove argument
(defn filtered-seq [elem-to-remove a-seq]
  (remove #(= elem-to-remove %) a-seq))

;; idiomatic naming
;; if you want a set, use a set from the beginning
;; destructuring rather than repeated usage of first
;; use rest to recur when the first item is guaranteed to be dropped
(defn idiomatic-parity [a-seq]
  (loop [result-set #{}
         [elem & others :as current-seq] a-seq]
    (cond (empty? current-seq)
          result-set
          (odd? (count-of elem current-seq))
          (recur (conj result-set elem) (filtered-seq elem others))
          :else
          (recur result-set (filtered-seq elem others)))))
```

Next, as requested, a version that uses `reduce` to accumulate the result:

```
;; mapcat allows us to return 0 or more results for each input
(defn reducing-parity [a-seq]
  (set
   (mapcat
    (fn [[k v]]
      (when (odd? v) [k]))
    (reduce (fn [result item]
              (update-in result [item] (fnil inc 0)))
            {}
            a-seq))))
```

But, reading over this, I notice that the reduce is just `frequencies`, a built in clojure function. And my `mapcat` was really just a hand-rolled `keep`, another built in.

```
(defn most-idiomatic-parity [a-seq]
  (set
   (keep
    (fn [[k v]]
      (when (odd? v) k))
    (frequencies a-seq))))
```

In Clojure we can refine our code, and as we recognize places where our logic replicates the built in functionality, we can simplify the code and make it more clear. Also, there is a good chance the built in is better optimized than our own work-alikes.

Comment: Except the version with `keep` doesn't handle nils as well as the version with `mapcat`.

Comment: what nils would `keep` not handle here? the result of the fn is always either nil or a number, and we don't want the nil

Comment: Huh? The keys in the map that `frequencies returns` are not numbers, but the items in the input collection. If the input is just numbers, as in your example input, that's fine, but `(most-idiomatic-parity [1 2 nil])` will return `#{1 2}` instead of `#{1 2 nil}`.

Answer (score 0):

*Is there a better way to achieve this?*

```
(defn parity [coll]
  (->> coll
       frequencies
       (filter (fn [[_ v]] (odd? v)))
       (map first)
       set))
```

For example,

```
(parity [1 1 1 2 1 2 1 3])
;#{1 3}
```

*How can this be done with `reduce` function of clojure*.

We can use `reduce` to rewrite `frequencies`:

```
(defn frequencies [coll]
  (reduce
   (fn [acc x] (assoc acc x (inc (get acc x 0))))
   {}
   coll))
```

... and again to implement `parity` in terms of it:

```
(defn parity [coll]
  (let [freqs (frequencies coll)]
    (reduce (fn [s [k v]] (if (odd? v) (conj s k) s)) #{} freqs)))
```

Comment: Thanks: error corrected - {} was wrong, must be #{}